# Select all elements from one column that have ONLY ONE value in an associated column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following database

```
Table A
id_a   
1
2
3
4

Table B
id_b  id_o   
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     5
5     8
6     2
7     5
8     1


Table C
id_a    id_b
1       3
1       2
3       6
2       8
4       4
4       7
```

I want to get all elements from A that have associated only one id_o from table B, where table C is the link between the two tables. So in this case it would only bring me

```
id_a  id_o
4     5
```

Since id_a=4 only has associated records from Table B with id_o=5

What I TRIED to do was:

```
SELECT
  c.id_a, b.id_o
FROM
  TableC c
JOIN
  TableB b
ON
  c.id_b = b.id_b
GROUP BY
  c.id_a, b.id_o
HAVING
  COUNT(id_o) = 1;
```

But this doesn't return what I want at all, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure about the result? Shouldn't it be (id_a, id_o) = (2, 1) and (id_a, id_o) = (3, 2), instead of (id_a, id_o) = (4, 5)?

Answer (score 1):

#### SQL statement

```
SELECT 
    ta.id_a,
    tb.id_o
FROM TableA AS ta
LEFT JOIN TableC AS tc ON tc.id_a = ta.id_a
LEFT JOIN TableB AS tb ON tb.id_b = tc.id_b
GROUP BY 
    ta.id_a,
    tb.id_o
HAVING COUNT(tb.id_o) = 1;
```

#### Description of the SQL statement:

- Select all records of `TableA`.
- Attach, e.g. join all corresponding details from `TableC` (link table)
- Attach, e.g. join all corresponding details from `TableB`
- Group by `TableA`'s `id_a` and `TableB`'s `id_o`.
- Calculate the number of `id_o`s for each group and filter the results by allowing only the ones having the number of `id_o`s equal 1.

#### Results:

```
id_a    id_o
------------
2       1
3       2
```

#### Notes:

- I also added a `TableA` record (`id_a = 5`) without any corresponding `id_b` or `id_o`.
- Alongside `TableA` details, you can even fetch the `TableB` details (and even `TableC` details) because the filtered grouped records represent individual `TableA` records. The condition is to `GROUP` on each of the fetched column. In other situations (like, for example, when you'd use `HAVING COUNT(tb.id_o) >= 1`) would not be right to fetch the `TableB` (or `TableC`) details alongside `TableA` details, because the results would not be correctly displayed.
- I'd also mention that, if you'd have said "*select all records from `TableC` where...*", then I would have begun my sql statement with `SELECT ... FROM TableC AS tc LEFT JOIN ...`, conform with the definition of `LEFT JOIN`: from the LEFT table will always be fetched all records, unconditionally. A filter can be afterwards applied.

#### Used table structure

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TableA`;
CREATE TABLE `TableA` (
  `id_a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TableB`;
CREATE TABLE `TableB` (
  `id_b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_o` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TableC`;
CREATE TABLE `TableC` (
  `id_a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

#### Used table data

```
INSERT INTO `TableA` (`id_a`)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

INSERT INTO `TableB` (`id_b`, `id_o`)
VALUES (1,2), (2,2), (3,2), (4,5), (5,8), (6,2), (7,5), (8,1);

INSERT INTO `TableC` (`id_a`, `id_b`)
VALUES (1,3), (1,2), (3,6), (2,8), (4,4), (4,7);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close:

```
SELECT c.id_a, MAX(b.id_o) as id_o
FROM TableC c JOIN
     TableB b
     ON c.id_b = b.id_b
GROUP BY c.id_a
HAVING MIN(id_o) = MAX(id_o);
```

This aggregates only by `id_a`.  It checks to see if `id_o` only has one value for `id_a`.  An alternative is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT id_o) = 1` in the `FROM` clause.  However, `COUNT(DISTINCT)` incurs more overhead than a simple `MAX()` or `MIN()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `distinct` and few modifications of your solution

```
SELECT c.id_a, MAX(b.id_o)
FROM  TableC c
JOIN  TableB b ON  c.id_b = b.id_b
GROUP BY c.id_a
HAVING COUNT(distinct id_o) = 1;
```